# Removing/Disabling kendotool tip from one of the Column of the grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using KendoGrid and I have applied Kendo tooltip to each "th" of the Grid as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Tooltip()
        .For("tr")
        .Filter("th")
        .Position(TooltipPosition.Top)
        .Width(120)
    )
```

bt In my Grid I have a Checkbox in the First Column and  I want to disable the Kendotool tip there
Here is the image. [image]

How to do that?
Please Suggest.

I am trying this using Jquery as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#InvoiceGrid").find("input[type=checkbox]").removeClass('k-animation-container k-tooltip-content');
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can u suggest the solution please?@OnaBai

Answer (score 1):

The filter property on the C# Kendo wrapper is really just a CSS selector. So you can make it so that the tooltip only applies to column headings that you're interested in. In your case, this is any column after the first, or "th:nth-child(n+2)".

```
@(
    Html.Kendo().Tooltip()
        .For("tr")
        .Filter("th:nth-child(n+2)")
        .Position(TooltipPosition.Top)
        .Width(120)
)
```